# DHCP starting before network is ready

Tags: debian, bash, dhcp, isc-dhcp, networkmanager

I am having a problem with my DHCP server. When it restarts the isc-dhcp-server does not get ready because the network (it uses NetworkManager) is not ready.

I put a sleep command in the isc-dhcp-server start script but when the server restarted the script erased the line with the sleep command.

How can I delay the DHCP start or restart when the network is ready?
Here is some information:

Linux Version

```
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)"
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="11"
VERSION="11 (bullseye)"
```

Journalctl

```
jan 09 07:50:22 server systemd[1]: Starting LSB: DHCP server...
jan 09 07:50:28 server isc-dhcp-server[579]: Launching IPv4 server only.
jan 09 07:50:30 server dhcpd[622]: WARNING: Host declarations are global.  They are not limited to the scope you declared them in.
jan 09 07:50:30 server dhcpd[632]: WARNING: Host declarations are global.  They are not limited to the scope you declared them in.
jan 09 07:50:31 server dhcpd[632]: Wrote 0 deleted host decls to leases file.
jan 09 07:50:31 server dhcpd[632]: Wrote 0 new dynamic host decls to leases file.
jan 09 07:50:31 server dhcpd[632]: Wrote 79 leases to leases file.
jan 09 07:50:31 server dhcpd[632]: 
jan 09 07:50:31 server dhcpd[632]: No subnet declaration for enp32s0 (no IPv4 addresses).
jan 09 07:50:31 server dhcpd[632]: ** Ignoring requests on enp32s0.  If this is not what
jan 09 07:50:31 server dhcpd[632]:    you want, please write a subnet declaration
jan 09 07:50:31 server dhcpd[632]:    in your dhcpd.conf file for the network segment
jan 09 07:50:31 server dhcpd[632]:    to which interface enp32s0 is attached. **
jan 09 07:50:31 server dhcpd[632]: 
jan 09 07:50:31 server dhcpd[632]: 
jan 09 07:50:31 server dhcpd[632]: Not configured to listen on any interfaces!
jan 09 07:50:31 server dhcpd[632]: 
jan 09 07:50:31 server dhcpd[632]: If you think you have received this message due to a bug rather
jan 09 07:50:31 server dhcpd[632]: than a configuration issue please read the section on submitting
jan 09 07:50:31 server dhcpd[632]: bugs on either our web page at www.isc.org or in the README file
jan 09 07:50:31 server dhcpd[632]: before submitting a bug.  These pages explain the proper
jan 09 07:50:31 server dhcpd[632]: process and the information we find helpful for debugging.
jan 09 07:50:31 server dhcpd[632]: 
jan 09 07:50:31 server dhcpd[632]: exiting.
jan 09 07:50:33 server isc-dhcp-server[579]: Starting ISC DHCPv4 server: dhcpdcheck syslog for diagnostics. ...
jan 09 07:50:33 server isc-dhcp-server[640]:  failed!
jan 09 07:50:33 server isc-dhcp-server[641]:  failed!
jan 09 07:50:33 server systemd[1]: isc-dhcp-server.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
jan 09 07:50:33 server systemd[1]: isc-dhcp-server.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
jan 09 07:50:33 server systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: DHCP server.
```

```
#> cat /etc/network/interfaces

# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

```
#> cat /etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf

# dhcpd.conf
#
# Sample configuration file for ISC dhcpd
#

option domain-name "server.local";
option domain-name-servers 8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4;

default-lease-time 600;
max-lease-time 7200;

ddns-update-style none;

authoritative;


subnet 192.168.1.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
        # — default gateway
        option routers 192.168.1.3;
        option subnet-mask 255.255.255.0;
        #option nis-domain "SERVER";
        option domain-name "SERVER";
        # Cloudflare
        option domain-name-servers 1.1.1.1, 1.0.0.1;
        option time-offset -18000;
        option ntp-servers 192.168.1.3;
        #option tftp-server-name "192.168.1.10";
        option broadcast-address 192.168.1.255;
        range 192.168.1.11 192.168.1.90;
        default-lease-time 21600;
        max-lease-time 43200;
        # Fixed IP addresses can also be specified for hosts.
    [...]
```

Thank you guys.

Comment: Have you tried adding `After=NetworkManager` to the service that starts the DHCP server?

Comment: Not yet. To be honest I did not find where I can make this modification. But I am thinking of making a timer to restart the service after 20 seconds the server starts. I don't know if the right way, but it can resolve my problem.

Comment: If you want to try it, you can just add `After=NetworkManager.service` to the `[Unit]` section of the `.service` file

Comment: Oh, right. But the problem is that I did not find where is the isc-dhcp-server.service file. using the `systemctl status isc-dhcp-server.service` it gives me the path `/system.slice/isc-dhcp-server.service` but I don't know how I can access it.

Comment: It looks like systemd slices are a whole other can of worms, I know nothing about how that works

Answer (score 0):

To order a service start after network is up, set `After=network-online.target` in the systemd service file.

Don't use `After=NetworkManager-wait-online.service`, because that is an implementation detail. `NetworkManager-wait-online.service` orders itself `Before=network-online.target`, so you get that ordering implicitly.

For example, do so via `systemctl edit isc-dhcp-server.service`.

Read the [manual page](https://networkmanager.dev/docs/api/latest/NetworkManager-wait-online.service.html), in particular about `ipv4.may-fail=no` and `ipv4.required-timeout` about how to tell NetworkManager that the interface is only ready with an IPv4 address.

A better, more robust solution may be to convince the DHCP server to dynamically cope with being started when the addresses are not there yet.

Answer (score 0):

What you can try to do is

`systemctl enable systemd-networkd.service systemd-networkd-wait-online.service`

And then

```
[Unit]
After=systemd-networkd-wait-online.service
Wants=systemd-networkd-wait-online.service
```

Source
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35805354/systemd-start-service-at-boot-time-after-network-is-really-up-for-wol-purpose

I usually edit the file directly in `/etc/systemd/system/` with vi or nano

And then a systemctl daemon-reload and a restart if the service comes up properly

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://serverfault.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://serverfault.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/577366)